# Path removal in connected graph.

Tags: graph-theory, path-connected

> Let $G$ be a connected graph such that $δ(G)≥k$. Proof there exists a path $P$ of length $k$ such that $G-P$ is connected.

I am not sure how do I actually approach this question. Do I consider contradiction or inductive proof, if so how. Really appreciate it alot

Comment: Could you please tell me what do you mean when you wrote $G-P$?

Comment: This statement seems false for small $k$. E.g. for $k=2$, any cycle is such a connected graph, but remove a path of length 2 from a cycle and you isolate a vertex.